# How can I center content on my Home page in the Featured Products widget

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm trying to center some content. I've inspected the elements and can't figure out how to add the correct changes to custom CSS. I'm using a widget shortcode so can't edit this directly in Elementor text editor.

I'm in WordPress and use Elementor as my page builder.I tried a generic "div" line, however that centered several things on the home page.  I'm looking to center Star Rating and the Add to Cart button.  Thanks for any advice.  New to working with code and feel like I'm barely missing it, but missing it nonetheless.

[Featured Products Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5GFl.jpg)

This is what I used to center the Product Title and Price.

```
.woocommerce-loop-product__title, h {text-align: center;}

span.price, h
{text-align: center;}
```

One of the elements when hovered over shows -

```
div.star-rating::before
```

Comment: I believe so, have tried using several combinations from the CSS panel.  My website is ottermountain.com if that helps any.

Comment: You can style the text pretty well directly in Elementor: https://elementor.com/help/text-editor-widget/

Comment: It's not the text editor widget, so I don't think that helps.

Comment: Your question is confusing, did you create this text in Elementor or not?

Comment: Yes, but it's shown as a "shortcode" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on CSS, but I think you can use this for the Stars.

```
.star-rating {
    margin: 0 auto 0 !important;
}
```

and you can use this for the Add to Cart button

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .button {
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-left: 4em;
}
```

This is how it looks for me.
[image]

if this help you, don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: That works great, thank you Syntax_Error.  If you're not an Expert, then I have more to learn that I thought!

Comment: This is good! I'd avoid important though, try to use a more specific compound class for the stars instead; include the container class the stars are in and keep going till it works. !important is usually a sign the code is not correct according to the CSS global cascade which causes issues later.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not an expert, but the option I was thinking was editing the css file directly. The problem is the margin properties defined by the theme.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the help and education, appreciate you much.